# Standard reference for K-means

Tags: references, k-means

When citing the K-means algorithm in a paper, what is the standard reference?

I ran into [this](https://scholar.google.dk/scholar?hl=en&q=+Some+Methods+for+classification+and+Analysis+of+Multivariate+Observations&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=) paper through some digging around but I am not entirely sure if this one is still the correct one.

I could potentially cite ESL but I wanted to know if people here had any opinion on this.

I am not looking for a reference to a specific implementation of the algorithm, just a generic reference.

Comment: Please note, supplementary to my comment just made, that the cited thread includes standard references as well as answering the question in the title.

Comment: @NickCox Ok great thanks! I had just ran into this. This is definitely a duplicate. Maybe a new question which I thought of then is whether one should cite both references or is J. MacQueen (1967) enough?

Comment: @Scortchi I am referencing k-means in a general sense, regardless of implementation or underlying algorithm to solve it. But after reading the paper by MacQueen I think that it is the only one I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to wikipedia, the term k-means was first introduced in the reference you refer to. The usual reference in the computer vision community for the algorithm, which solves the k-means problem, is:

> Lloyd, Stuart P. "Least squares quantization in PCM." Information Theory, IEEE Transactions on 28.2 (1982): 129-137.